# How to solve a sequence-dependent parallel machine scheduling problem where a plan as to be provided as solution?

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I am looking for any leads which could help me in solving this problem. I am not sure where to start with. It would be nice if someone could provide me relevant links to solve this problem.

**Problem:**

**Definition of a process order:**
To process a material of quantity 1kg to make the final product of that material. Each Material comes in 1kg order. So there could be multiple orders which are to be processed in a given time, say 8 orders of "Material 1" would mean processing 1kg of "Material 1" eight times.

**Availability**:
There are 3 types of materials that are to be processed on a processing station (3 in no.) to make final products of those respective materials. There is a material to station mapping available. Let's say:

1. Material 1 can be processed in Station 1 and Station 2.
2. Material 2 can be processed in Station 1 and Station 3.
3. Material 3 can be processed in Station 2 only.

**Time to process each material is provided:**

1. Material 1 -> 1 hour to process and .5 hour to clean the station.
2. Material 2 -> 0.5 hours to process and .25 hour to clean the station.
3. Material 3 -> 2 hours to process and 1 hour to clean the station.

**Cleaning** is only required when two different types of materials are to be processed on a station one after another. For e.g.:

1. If Material 2 follows Material 1 in processing on the same station, there will be .5 hours of cleaning time required.
2. If Material 2 follows Material 2 in processing on the same station, there will be no cleaning time required.

**Aim:**
To provide the best schedule plan for each station. i.e the order in which the provided process orders should be executed on a station.

**Objective Function:**
To reduce the Cleaning time.

For e.g. If I can process some quantity of Material 1 in the next 4 hours, I will stick to one of the stations to process the whole quantity rather than parallelly processing half of the orders on Station 2.

**Madontory Constraints:**

- Concept of preferred stations: There are preferred stations for a material, i.e. if station 1 and station 2 both are available, station 1 is preferred for Material 1 and Material 2.

**Optional Contraints:**

- Priority: If a priority is assigned to process order, then that PO (1kg of material) should be executed first.
- Time constraints: If asked for a plan for the next 8 hours, only the next 8 hours of planning should be provided.

**What I have done:**
The most hopeful solution is coming from https://ibmdecisionoptimization.github.io/tutorials/html/Scheduling_Tutorial.html, however, I am yet to reach any conclusion. The problem looks too complex to me.

As of now, I am thinking to prepare a solution space with permutations of all possible solutions and give the result back with the lowest time consumption. The biggest hurdle to be in that case is providing a sequence. This could be computationally expensive as I have 200+ materials and 30+ stations. I am looking to solve this in Python.

PS: I couldn't think of a proper title, would be nice if you a can suggest one.

Comment: 1) Are you sure the objective function is the cleaning time and not the overall production time? 2) In case of working shift, do you need to perform a cleaning at the end of the shift?

Comment: 1) I think lesser cleaning time and overall production time will have the same solutions unless there the Process Orders are fewer in numbers. So I would accept your solution as well. 2) Yes. Cleaning is required at end of the shift.

Comment: I'm asking because the solution changes, since you could ignore parallelisation and minimize the cleaning time, but the solution would be a much higher timespan

Comment: I think you are right. For now, I would want to reduce the production time as I feel in a case where other stations are free (which is generally not) manual decisions can be taken.

Comment: This is called "sequence-dependent parallel machine scheduling". The MIP models for this are not totally trivial.

Comment: +1 for Erwins keyword/classification. This should bring up tons of scientific papers. I would start with CP/SAT(LP)-Hybrid based [ortools](https://developers.google.com/optimization) (CP-SAT solver; it has a Python-API + it's free). I don't see anything *annoying* in regards to modelling this (and i can say i modelled generalizations of this including additional lot-sizing). It surely is not trivial (circuit-constraint!), but not as bad as MIPs would be. Black-box performance is also incredibly good (given that this problem is very tough).Start with example `scheduling_with_transitions_sat.py`